# How to practically measure the resolution (PPR) of incremental rotary encoder?

Tags: microcontroller, encoder, rotary-encoder

I have an incremental rotary encoder that I can't determine its model number thus I can't get its data sheet, How can I measure its resolution manually?

Comment: Is it optical or mechanical? Can you post a picture?

Comment: @Mattman944 it's an optical encoder

Comment: you can count the output pulses with a frequency counter or an oscilloscope and rotate it by hand one revolution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters you might hook it up as you would any encoder, turn it 360 degrees and see how many counts you get.

Comment: I tried that but it's not precise, I know I will always get measuring error but the values I get vary a lot, between 2400 and 2700, Thank you for the suggestion anyway

Comment: That's probably because you're not being precise in your turning of the shaft.  Rather than do it by hand, hook it up to a stepper motor and turn it EXACTLY 360 degrees.

Comment: I haven't thought of that, Thank you!

Comment: Even by hand you may be able to do better than that if you can fix a small arm to the shaft to point at a farther away point.  I was thinking if you're uncertain of the sensing apparatus be sure not to exceed the maximum turn rate or your sample rate.

Comment: Average over multiple revolutions to get more precise.  Turn N number of revolutions and then divide the total number of counts by N.